# Actualizar OpenSSL servidor CentOS

Tags: linux

tengo un servidor de pruebas con CentOS 6.7 y la version de OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips.

Actualice el OpenSSL a la version 1.0.2g pero en los headers que regresa aun me sigue marcando la version anterior, estos son los comandos que ejecute.

```
# cd openssl-1.0.2a
# ./config
# make
# make test
# make install
```

¿Alquien tiene alguna idea a que se deba que aun tome la version anterior?

Comment: Quien devuelve los headers incorrectos, Apache? Nginx?

Comment: ¿No se puede actualizar con yum ?

Comment: Apache es quien regresa el dato y no se puede actualizar con yum. Al final lo que hice es configurar apache para que no regrese esas cabeceras.

Answer (score 1):

Hola intenta ejecutar

```
 yum update openssl
```